# Change value inside directive template and watch for changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside my directive template I have `ng-disabled` I need to change it when `validationScope` is changed....

Here is my directive:

```
var addComment = {
    link: link,
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        validationScope:'@'
    },
    template: '<button type="submit" ng-disabled="validationScope" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Send</button>'
};
```

In my html I put like this:

```
<mydirective validation-scope="<%mainComment.mainTxt.$invalid%>"></mydirective>
```

Problem whith my code is `ng-disabled` will allways be `true` even if `mainComment.mainTxt.$invalid%` is changed...

Also if I in directive template put like this: `{{validationScope}}` I can see value change to: true/false...

Answer (score 0):

**Do this it might work now:**

```
template:'<button type="submit" ng-disabled="{{validationScope}}" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Send</button>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Angular bug...

Probmel is `<%mainComment.mainTxt.$invalid%>` will return string 'true'/'false' to directive...

I solve it like this:

in link I added:

```
scope.$watch('validationScope',function()
{
    if(scope.validationScope === 'true')
    {
        scope.validationScope = true;
    }
    else if(scope.validationScope === 'false')
    {
        scope.validationScope = false;
    }
});
```

Also we need add ths rule: `transclude: true` so we can change scope from outside....